# ANTLR: unexpected character

Tags: c, antlr, interpreter, antlr3

Given the following ANTLR grammar:

```
tokens
{
   SET;
   UNKNOWN;
   LIST;
}


statement : SET_KEYWORD list = value_list -> ^(SET $list)
          | UNKNOWN_KEYWORD -> ^(UNKNOWN);

value_list : element += value (COMMA_KEYWORD element += value)* -> ^(LIST $element+);

value : STRING_KEYWORD;


SET_KEYWORD : 'SET';

UNKNOWN_KEYWORD : .;

fragment STRING_KEYWORD : '"' ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')* '"';
```

When one parses the following text (i.e. without closing the double-quotes):

```
SET "example
```

ANTLR gives the following error:

```
TEST(1) : lexer error 1 :
        Unexpected character at offset 12, (end of input).
         This indicates a poorly specified lexer RULE
         or unterminated input element such as: "STRING["]
         The lexer was matching from line 1, offset 3, which
         looks like this:
                "example
```

One would think that the UNKNOWN_KEYWORD will catch up this type of issues. How can one fix the grammar so that the aforementioned error message is not shown anymore?

Answer (score 0):

## Main bug

The main bug of your grammar is describing  `UNKNOWN_KEYWORD` and `STRING_KEYWORD` as  lexer rules. Your parser does not match `SET "example` input because the lexer has the [following](http://meri-stuff.blogspot.ru/2011/09/antlr-tutorial-expression-language.html#LexerBasics):

> Lexer looks for the first longest matching rule. In other words, if multiple rules match the input, the longest one is selected.

When the lexer meets the `"` which could be matched as `UNKNOWN_KEYWORD` and as beginning of `STRING_KEYWORD`, it decides to match input as `STRING_KEYWORD` because  this rule is longer than `UNKNOWN_KEYWORD`.

So, it will be better to rewrite these rules as parser rules. Let the lexer match more simple tokens.

## Other bugs

Besides these there are other bugs in your grammar:

- Missing `options` block for describe output type for using AST operators in rules.
- Missing `+` after `UNKNOWN_KEYWORD` in the `statement` rule. Without `+` you say that statement is a `SET_KEYWORD value_list` or any **single**  character.
- Missing rules for newline and whitespace.
- Missing `EOF` in the end of `statement` rule. The input like `SET "abc"bla-bla-bla` will be parsed as `SET_KEYWORD value_list` with AST `(SET (LIST "abc"))` i.e. `bla-bla-bla` will be ignored without `EOF`.
- Missing description of the `COMMA_KEYWORD` rule.
- Describing `STRING_KEYWORD` as a fragment rule. If the rule is fragment, the parser will never get the token, described by this rule.

## AST issue

If you rewrite `UNKNOWN_KEYWORD` and `STRING_KEYWORD` as a parser rules and try your parser for `SET "example"` input you get the following AST:

```
(SET (LIST " e x a m p l e "))
```

I.e. `"example"` is not an entire node of AST. There are separate nodes for every character, because one node in AST constructs for one token in common case. But it can be resolved by creating imaginary token and creating node via calling constructor for `CommonTree` class (see [ANTLR 3 Runtime 3.5.2 API](http://www.antlr3.org/api/Java/index.html)):

```
 value :  st = string_keyword -> {new CommonTree(new CommonToken(KEYWORD, $st.text))};
```

## Resulting grammar

So, your grammar may look as follows:

```
options {
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
   SET;
   UNKNOWN;
   LIST;
   KEYWORD;
}

statement : ((SET_KEYWORD value_list)=> SET_KEYWORD list= value_list NEWLINE -> ^(SET $list)
            | unknown_keyword+ NEWLINE -> ^(UNKNOWN)
            )
            EOF;

value_list : element += value (COMMA_KEYWORD element += value)* -> ^(LIST $element+);

value :  st= string_keyword -> {new CommonTree(new CommonToken(KEYWORD,$st.text))};

NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;
WS: (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+ {skip();};
COMMA_KEYWORD: ',';
SET_KEYWORD : 'SET';
QUOTES:'"';
LETTER:('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
ANY:.;
string_keyword : QUOTES LETTER* QUOTES ;
unknown_keyword : SET_KEYWORD|QUOTES|LETTER|COMMA_KEYWORD|ANY;
```